# MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld on deploy app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

My app works very well on my local machine but when I deploy it on Heroku I can not connect with my Database I got an error: `MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld`. I have allowed access from any IP address in Mongo Atlas.

Here is my code to connect with Mongo Atlas:

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://drdung1999:onichan123@cluster0.lbxxt.mongodb.net/pinet2?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false});
    // try connect mongodb
    const db = mongoose.connection;

    // log result
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connect mongDB success');
    });
```

Comment: May it can be a ssl problem? Try with no ssl: ssl=false
 Like this mongodb+srv://drdung1999:onichan123@cluster0.lbxxt.mongodb.net/pinet2?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=false

Comment: I have tried this but it not work. I got the same error: `MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld`.

Comment: my code run very well on my localhost but it does not work when I deploy it

Comment: I updated my password using autogenerate password and use " instead of `

Comment: Yes I used it but the result hasn't changed

Comment: is there character like #, @, ! in the password url?

Comment: can you try 
const dbURI = "mongodb+srv://drdung1999:onichan123@cluster0.lbxxt.mongodb.net/pinet2?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(dbURI,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false}).then((result) => {
  console.log('connected to db')
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));

Comment: I tried your code but it still not working, my password does not have any special character. My code in Github https://github.com/drdung1999/pinet. When I deploy it does not working but when I run on local it still work

Answer (score 0):

It is because of using special character in your password. Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274289/21185004

> Use the percent sign followed by the HEX code of the special character you've used (i.e., the number 40).

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the special characters `(: / ? # [ ] @)` in your `password` or `username` as follows

   a. `@ = %40`

   b.`' = %27`

   c. `! = %21`

   d. [More](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

   e.g: `p@ssw0rd'9'!` becomes `p%40ssw0rd%279%27%21`
2. The other way is to is create a new user with the password which does not have any special character.