# I'm trying to connect monogoDB with node.js, but the terminal is showing MongoAPIError: URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-development-server

I'm trying to connect MongoDB with node.js, but the terminal is showing MongoAPIError: URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld

- **Backend Code**

I have written monogoDB code in a database file and added/required the file path in the backend file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

dotenv.config({path: './config.env'})
require('./database-connection.js')

const port = 80
```

- **MongoDB Database Code**

Database connection file name: **database-connection.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const db = mongodb+srv://kumbamshyam:Superman@123@cluster0.apij4.mongodb.net/ecommerce-website?retryWrites=true&w=majority

mongoose.connect(db).then(()=>{ 
    console.log('conencted successfuly');
}).catch((err)=>{ 
    console.log("Error received= " + err)
})
```

- **<----- Error Code ----->**

```
Error received= MongoAPIError: URI must include hostname, domain name, and tld
```

***Any solution for this problems***

Comment: Did you simply miss the quotes around connection string?

Comment: Try URL-encode the `@` in the password.

Comment: @Joe. it's working ✌️

Answer (score 11):

Probably it's because you've used the special character "@" in your password, and a character like this "must be converted using percent encoding" (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples).

Use the percent sign followed by the HEX code of the special character you've used (*i.e.*, the number 40).

So, your password must be written this way: Superman%40123

Comment: Thanks! These [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error by removing special characters from my password MongoDB User.
Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by eliminating special characters from my MongoDB user password. I hope this solution proves effective for you.